# How to check for a String value in an Array using Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I'm kinda new to programming, but I can't figure out how to use a String Scanner to see if it is present in an Array (If Array contains "Apple" and the Scanner returns "Apple", Print "Present"). I'm using Eclipse Mars 4.5.0, and the code I have up to now is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String answer = "null"; //Initialize "answer"
    String[] Fruit;         //Array of Strings called "Fruit"
    Fruit = new String[10]; //"Fruit" has 10 spaces
    //Strings saved in "Fruit":
    Fruit[0] = "Apple";
    Fruit[1] = "Banana";
    Fruit[2] = "Mango";
    Fruit[3] = "Pear";

    //The actual programme:
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a fruit:");
    answer = input.next();
                                                            //If the answer is 'Fruit[0]'
    if (answer == Fruit[0] || answer == Fruit[1] ||         //OR 'Fruit[1]' OR etc,
        answer == Fruit[2] || answer == Fruit[3]) {         //Print "available"
        System.out.println("This fruit is available.");
    }
                                                            //If the answer isn't 'Fruit[0]'
    else if (answer != Fruit[0] && answer != Fruit[1] &&    // AND not 'Fruit[1]' AND not
            answer != Fruit[2] && answer != Fruit[3]){      //etc, Print "not available"
        System.out.println("This fruit is not available right now.");
    }
}
```

However, it always returns "not available", same goes for a While-loop: it somehow doesn't seem to check whether it is even present in the Arraylist or not.

Does anybody know how to fix this? I'd love to know because I couldn't find any similar question anywhere on the internet.

**EDIT**: Odd, I searched for it quite a number of times, guess I missed one, sorry for duplicating!

Comment: You can't compare **Strings** using **==** operator instead you have to use **equals** method of the String class for String comparison. Alsoyou don't need to evaluate any condition in else part.

Comment: And read about java naming conventions - variable names go camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

**instead of using**

```
if (answer == Fruit[0] || answer == Fruit[1] ||         //OR 'Fruit[1]' OR etc,
        answer == Fruit[2] || answer == Fruit[3])
```

**use:**

```
if (TextUtils.equals(answer,Fruit[0]) || TextUtils.equals(answer,Fruit[1]) ||         
        TextUtils.equals(answer,Fruit[2]) || TextUtils.equals(answer,Fruit[3]))
```

> Strings are always compared with **equals** method not  by **==** method

Comment: Okay I am new here, will keep these suggestions in mind, thanks :)

Comment: Better now. But don't expect much upvotes for such content. I know it is tempting to answer such questions - but they have been answered long time ago.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't recognise 'TextUtils'? (Sorry, I am very new to this)

Comment: @G.Heiden you need to import TextUtils at top of the class.

`import android.text.TextUtils;`